# Can someone explain me the following example?

Tags: algorithm, clojure, functional-programming, lisp

Well I'm new in clojure and I was reviewing the literature of the function mapcat in (http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/mapcat) and I found the following sample:

```
(mapcat (fn [[k v]] 
                 (for [[k2 v2] v] 
                   (concat [k k2] v2)))
         '{:a {:x (1 2) :y (3 4)}
           :b {:x (1 2) :z (5 6)}})

((:a :x 1 2) (:a :y 3 4) (:b :x 1 2) (:b :z 5 6))
```

I tried to understand but I got confused how does the key and values work, I'm not sure what is the exactly value of k, k2, v and v2 when the functions for and concat use them.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is applied to each key-value tuple of the incoming map. The `[[k v]]` destructures the tuple, so that in the first case, `k` will have the value `:a`, and `v` the value `{:x (1 2) :y (3 4)}`.

The for loop the iterates through tuples in `v`, destructuring again, so that in the first case, `k2` will be `:x` and `v2` will be `(1 2)`.

This is passed to concat, so that our first entry will be `(:a :x 1 2)`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this example will help you understand what `mapcat` does, but it's not a great example of well-written code: it is a rather confusing way to write the much-simpler

```
(for [[k v] '{:a {:x (1 2) :y (3 4)}
              :b {:x (1 2) :z (5 6)}}
      [k2 v2] v]
  (list* k k2 v2))
```

Mixing the `mapcat` and the `for` together in the same place makes it harder to see that all that's happening is a nested sequence comprehension.